# Accessing scope form ng repeat in new modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to create a modal that will open an articles main reading, however I cannot seem to get the scope. Right now the JSON file is just the excerpt eventually it will be a full article so the point is when you click read more it will show the full article.

Here is a plunker of my it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OTf2179YNnNq2O1Ue18Z?p=preview

It's obviously missing a lot of the styling etc, I just wanted to get the base of it on there.

I know ng-repeat creates a new scope, and so I should be able to access this scope to get what I want but I've been bashing my head against a wall trying to figure out exactly how to get that scope. I've read a few related questions however they all use a either the Bootstrap modal or similar and I didn't seem to see the relevant code.

Any ideas?

***EDIT:***

Passing the article through the openArticle function properly links the article, however it still doesn't show up in the modal.

```
app.controller('ArticleListCtrl', function($scope, $http, researchArticleModal) {
    $http.get('research/articles.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.articles = data;

        $scope.openArticle = function(article) {
            console.log(article);
            $scope.fromFactory = researchArticleModal();
        }
    });
});
```

Console logs the correct title. I updated the plnkr.

EDIT 2:

I think the issue is that modal creates it's own scope that is outside of the controllers scope.  Could this be the issue I am running into?

EDIT:

So, the issue appears to be that the factory that creates my modal creates its own scope. I attempted injecting $scope into the factory but that threw an error, still no luck.

Comment: be sure that your objects in scope are not directly attached to `$scope` .   `$scope.myObject` => bad,    `$scope.anyObject.myObject` => good.  Otherwise, you might have a lot of issues with scope hierarchies.

Comment: I don't think you need the $parent. since the children will inherit from the parent.  Are you sure your code for the modal is working correctly?  I'd test that independently to confirm there are not issues with it.

Comment: Darryl, what do you mean? The modal definitely fires. I believe nesting the function inside the controller is why I need the $parent. without the $parent nothing fires at all.

Comment: no need for $parent at all, see my first comment

Comment: Huh. I swear earlier the function wouldn't run without the $parent but you are absolutely right. I removed the $parent and it still runs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you pass the article into the openArticle method that is defined on the parent scope.

Your footer's ngClick would then look like:

```
<footer><a href="" ng-click="$parent.openArticle(article)">Read More</a></footer>
```

You could then set a property on your scope equal to the currently selected article, and use that to display in your modal dialog.

```
app.controller('ArticleListCtrl', function($scope, $http, researchArticleModal) {
$http.get('research/articles.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.articles = data;


});
 $scope.openArticle = function(article) {
     console.log(article);
     $scope.selectedArticle = article;
     $scope.fromFactory = researchArticleModal();
 }
```

});

In your modal dialog's markup you could access properties on the scope's selectedArticle.

Like:

```
<div>{{selectedArticle.fullArticle}}</div>
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: I console logged the scope and was able to get the scope down.

Comment: Sorry for the two comments. Pressed the enter too soon.

    artile.title = $scope.articles[1].title; 

Gets me the second articles title. I am going to try your way as it probably makes more sense, originally I was going to set it as the index.

Comment: Once you have access to the article within the openArticle method, can't you use that to access your fullArticle property to display in the modal window?

Comment: How would I go about getting access to the article in the openArticle method?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you are opening the modal, but you could set a property on your scope equal to the currently selected article, and then use that in your modal.

Comment: In the plnkr I have the modal. The modal is a factory that is called on a click.

Comment: I think the issue is the modal has it's own scope that isn't seeing the article at all. It's logging the correct title for instance but it isn't showing up in the modal. So maybe my modal is the issue?

Comment: Okay, so after a lot of research. My modal is creating a new scope with scope = $rootScope.$new. I tried changing $rootScope to $scope and it creates it's own issue.

Comment: Changing scope from scope = $rootScope.new(); to var scope = $rootScope.$$childHead.$$childTail; allows me to use it. I feel this has got to be an awful practice...but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass in article in your openArticle() function like

```
<a href="" ng-click="$parent.openArticle(article)">Read More</a>
```

Comment: This almost works however my modal creates a new scope and therefore cannot access the article still. How could I make my factory/modal not create a new scope or even access the other scope?